# Redirecting to a controller with sub-actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm completely new to MVC, so pardon if I'm using the wrong terminology.  I'm building a controller that uses the following format, to display a project, and a step within that project.

Note:  I'm using MVC5 which uses the newly introduced route attributes.

```
'/project/1/step/2
<Route("{ProjectID}/Step/{StepNumber:int}")>
Function ProjStep(ProjectID As String, StepNumber As Integer) As String
   Return String.Format("Project {0} Step {1}", ProjectID, StepNumber)
End Function
```

The above works as expected.  But I also want to handle the case where a user only specifies the project and not the step.

```
'/Project/1
<Route("{ProjectID}")>
Sub Projuate(ProjectID As String)
   'Automatically start the user at step 555  
   'How do I send the user to the URL /Project/ProjectID/Step/555  
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi WhiskerBiscuit - could you accept one of the answers below? Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Apologies if syntax is a bit off - I do my MVC in C#.

You can either call the step Action directly or redirect to it.

Former (this will leave URL as /Project/1):

```
Function Projuate(projectID As String)
  Return ProjStep(projectID,555)
End Sub
```

Latter (will end up on /Project/1/Step/555):

```
Function Projuate(projectID As String)
  Return Redirect(Url.Action("ProjStep", new{ ProjectID = projectID, StepNumber=555})
End Sub
```

I don't know whether T4MVC works with VB but I would check that out - as it means you can get rid of those magic strings and get some nice extensions for creating URLs.

EDIT NOTE: Changed Sub to Function.

Comment: You can't 'Return' from a 'Sub'. Also, better to point out that the later is a client side redirect - which is probably better in this instance.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I've changed Subs to Functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the default value to the route is probably the easiest way:

```
<Route("{ProjectID}/Step/{StepNumber:int=555}")>
Function ProjStep(ProjectID As String, StepNumber As Integer) As String
    Return String.Format("Project {0} Step {1}", ProjectID, StepNumber)
End Function
```

p.s. I hope it comes after the int - it might be StepNumber=5:int for all I know.